# Inexpensive Method of International Swift Transfer for Low Dollar Amounts?

Tags: united-states, banking, money-transfer, international-transfer, poland

I am dealing with a beareaucratic government office in Europe in order to get some family records. They will only accept SWIFT transfers and have provided me with two different accounts I need to send money to, both with an IBAN number. However, the total amount I owe to each of these accounts is less than $3.00 ($0.50 and $2.33)

Is there any inexpensive way to accomplish this (perhaps online) without having to pay the exorbitant international transfer fees at my bank, and for two transactions?

From: USA
To:  Poland

Comment: From which country to which country ... it may help answers

Comment: This may help - http://www.forbes.com/sites/kostaperic/2012/05/29/faster-better-cheaper-ways-to-transfer-money-chapter-1-paypal/

Answer (score 1):

The best would be to find someone in that country to make a payment on behalf of you.

Other option is to use remittance services like Western union. It allows transfers to bank Account in Poland. You can fund by debiting your Card or Bank Account in US. If you debit your Card, there may be some fees as it would be treated as Cash Advance.